# Existe alguma maneira de reverter a minificação de javascript?

Tags: javascript, gulpjs

Uma vez que o arquivo tenha sido minificado usando, por exemplo, o `uglifyJS` é possível tornar ele legível novamente?

Se sim, como?

obs: Uso o `GulpJS` como *task runner*

Comment: É [isso](http://jsbeautifier.org/) que está procurando?

Comment: Você consegue voltar a identação. Já o nome das variáveis e funcoes não tem como.

Answer (score 4):

Tendo um arquivo minificado não há como saber qual o nome que as variáveis e funções tinham antes.

É possivel reformatar para a indentação ficar correta, mas não "adivinhar" os nomes antigos.

Para reformatar, usando o Gulp, encontrei [este plugin (gulp-indent)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-indent).

```
var indent = require("gulp-indent");

gulp.src("./src/*.ext")
    .pipe(indent({
        tabs:true,
    amount:1
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você só quiser reverter a minificação para fins de debugacão, os debugadores do chrome e do firefox são capazes de reindentar o código minificado para você.